# Storing and retrieving a tree in MongoDB : Embedded documents vs Parent References?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Coming from a relation DB background, the only way I could think of storing a tree was like this :

Relational **treeData** :

```
{
    _id: docID-1,
    itemName : 'Main Root',
    parent: null
},
{
    _id: docID-2,
    itemName: 'Child 1',
    parent: docID-1
},
{
    _id: docID-3,
    itemName: 'Child 2',
    parent: docID-1
}
```

For which I can retrieve the records with `db.collection('treeData').find()` and use recursion to retrieve the data in a tree structure.

But MongoDB offers embedded documents, which re-structures the tree into :

```
{
    _id: docID-1,
    itemName : 'Main Root',
    children: [
         {
            _id: docID-2,
             itemName: 'Child 1'
         },
         {
            _id: docID-3,
             itemName: 'Child 2'
         }
    ]
}
```

My question is what would be the best way to retrieve (print) this tree if using the embedded documents approach?

Also, I aim to have a find `category/child category` by initial characters, which I can do for the first approach with like this :

```
db.collection('treeData').find({ name : 'abc' })
```

What would be an efficient way to do it using embedded documents?

Comment: It depends on how you need to consume it. In the first example, each tree node is a document, which makes it much easier to query at the db level. In the second example, you have 1 document that represents your entire tree structure, so to get what you need youll probably have to pull the document before you can search through it.

Comment: I've dealt with this before, and your first example seems more practical. However, for my purposes, I had a UI component that expected my data to be in tree structure, and not an array of nodes. So instead of having to convert my array to a tree structure, I just stored it in the db as is.

Comment: Thanks for the response @IsaacVidrine. Can you suggest what would be the best way to get the tree structure using the first approach. Should I first get all the `records/documents` and then sort them using JS or Should I first fetch only the parent documents (having `parent: null`) and then recursively query the db for children documents?

Comment: I would probably grab all documents and then use a recursive function to loop through and put them into a tree structure.